# inverse FFT for creating pattern

Tags: ifft

I have created  a code which created the plot below.
The heart of the code is the AF expression.(array factor)
I want to do the inverse process , to take  the plot do the inverse of it and somehow to find using optimization the coeffects(genetic algorithm) which will recreate the plot.
my plot is from -90 to 90 degrees what could be done next to continue the process?
Is there a manual you could reccomend?
Thanks.

```
theta=linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,1000);
f=5.6;

N=6;

lambda=300/f;
d=0.8*lambda;

theta_0=pi*((0)/180);
amplitude_norm_V=[0.05,0.3,0.75,1,0.75,0.3,0.05];
k=(2*pi)/lambda;
delta=k*d*cos(theta_0);
x=sqrt(1/(sum(amplitude_norm_V.^2)));
real_voltage=amplitude_norm_V.*x;
real_power=(real_voltage.^2);
sum(real_power);
phases=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]



total=0;
tot=0;
for z=1:6
AF=real_voltage(z)*exp(1i*(phases(z)/180*pi))*exp(-1i*(z-1)*k*d*cos(theta)+1i*(z-1)*delta);
total=total+AF;

end
plot((theta/pi)*180,20*log10(total));

sin_p=cos(theta_0)+lambda/d;
```

[image]

Comment: You have seven factors but only sequence through six of them (z=1:6), was that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

The OP has only sequenced through six of the elements to get the result shown. I used the same 6 elements to replicate the result and show how to reverse that with a least squares solution.

We can inverse the pattern back to the coefficients using linear algebra resulting in the least squares solution. To show this let me first demonstrate creating the pattern using linear algebra as:

$$A = c_n H \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Where:

$A$:  1x1000 row vector for the pattern (as plotted in dB by the OP) 
$c_n$: 1x6 row vector for the coefficients (`real_voltage`) 
$H$: 6x1000 matrix, each row is a pattern for each of the six elements.

Each row of $H$ is given as:

$h_n(\theta) = e^{-j n kd(\cos(\theta)- \cos(\theta_o))}$

With

$k = 2\pi/\lambda$ 
$d=0.8\lambda$ 
$\theta$ = spatial direction angle from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, 1000 samples.
$n$ = antenna index $0$ through $5$ (to match OP's plot, omitting the last element).

There was also a phase multiplier that could be included as a 6x1000 matrix as an element by element product in the computation for $H$, but the OP used all zeros so I omitted it from the formulation above, but is shown in the MATLAB code below which replicates the OP's plot:

```
theta=linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,1000);
f=5.6;
N=6;
lambda=300/f;
d=0.8*lambda;
theta_0=pi*((0)/180);
amplitude_norm_V=[0.05,0.3,0.75,1,0.75,0.3];
k=(2*pi)/lambda;
x=sqrt(1/(sum(amplitude_norm_V.^2)));
real_voltage=amplitude_norm_V.*x;
phases=zeros(6,1000);
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6]';
H = exp(1j*(phases/180*pi)).*exp(-1j*(z-1)*k*d *(cos(theta)-cos(theta_0)))
A = real_voltage * H;
plot((theta/pi)*180,20*log10(A));
```

[image: confirmation of pattern]

Given equation \ref{1} for the pattern as $A$ we can solve for $c_n$ using linear algebra as follows:

We wish to inverse $H$ to isolate $c_n$, but $H$ is not a square matrix so cannot be inverted. So what we can do is multiply both sides by the transpose of $H$, resulting in a form that has $H H^T$ as a square matrix that can be inverted:

$$AH^T = c_n HH^T \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Now we can invert $HH^T$ and isolate $c_n$ by multiplying both sides by $(HH^T)^{-1}$:

$$AH^T(HH^T)^{-1} = c_n (HH^T) (HH^T)^{-1}\tag{3}\label{3}$$

resulting in the least squares solution for the coefficients $c_n$ as:

$$c_n = AH^T(HH^T)^{-1} \tag{4}\label{4}$$

Given $A$ and $H$, MATLAB will solve for $c_n$ directly by using the right matrix division operator `/`, solving for $c_n = A/H$ as the least squares solution detailed above:

```
cn = A/H
```

Results in:

```
Columns 1 through 4:
0.032915 + 0.000000i   0.197492 + 0.000000i   0.493731 - 0.000000i   0.658308 - 0.000000i
Columns 5 and 6:
0.493731 + 0.000000i   0.197492 + 0.000000i
```

Similarly, given an alternate pattern for $A$, the above will provide the coefficients $c_n$ to match that pattern as a least squares solution (will have the least squares error for the given degrees of freedom, assuming the target pattern or something close to the target pattern can be achieved with the number of elements provided).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152342/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-boschen-inverse-fft-for-creating-pattern); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.