# Iterative GA algorithm For Antenna Pattern Matching

Tags: phase

The following code creates a cosecant squared radiation pattern.
There are phases and an amplitude_norm_V vector which are the coefficients of an Array Factor (AF) expression as the response of an array of isotropic antenna elements.
I am looking to create a Genetic Algorithm (GA) that given known AF data will recreate phases and amplitude coefficients.  Here is a [link](https://www.irjet.net/archives/V7/i5/IRJET-V7I51434.pdf)  describing the Genetic Algorithm.

How to implement it?

```
amplitude_norm_V=[0.3213,0.4336,0.7539,1,0.7817,0.3201,0.32,0.3261];

x=sqrt(1/(sum(amplitude_norm_V.^2)));
real_voltage=amplitude_norm_V.*x;
real_power=(real_voltage.^2);
sum(real_power);
phases=[129.9121,175.4215,-144.6394,-116.9071,-93.7603,-60.0165,55.2841,89.4477]
norm_phases=phases-175.4215;
theta=linspace(0,pi,1000);
theta_0=pi*(135.315/180);
f=5.6;

N=10;

lambda=300/f;
k=(2*pi)/lambda;
d=0.8*lambda;
total=0;
tot=0;
for z=1:8
AF=real_voltage(z)*exp(1i*(phases(z)/180*pi))*exp(-1i*(z-1)*k*d*cos(theta));
total=total+AF;
tot=tot+AF.^2;
end
plot((theta/pi)*180,20*log10(total));
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain your acronyms. I think AF is supposed to be Adaptive Filter but I don't know what GA means. Also please add some comments to your code. We can't mind read.

Comment: GA is genetic algorithm.currently real_voltage and phases coeffients construct the AF . However i want to take AF data and do optimization and find the  real_voltage and phases coeffients.

Comment: @user70731 please **edit** your question to explain **all** acronyms. Thank you!

Comment: I did explain , its a reverse engineering optimization problem of recreating amplitude_norm_V and phases coefficent from AF data being plotted.

Comment: Can you explain why this must be iterative vs the solution provided here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/93379/21048  (If you have the entire pattern why not solve for the least square minimum error directly?)

Comment: because i want to learn another method,purely educational purpose

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [DSP.SE #93368](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93368/inverse-fft-for-creating-pattern/93379#93379) see how this same problem was solved directly and relatively efficiently with linear algebra. Below shows how this can be solved using a genetic algorithm as desired by the OP with the following results:

[image: Error vs Iteration]

[image: Final Pattern Match]

The following MATLAB / Octave code operates on `total` from OP's code as the Target Pattern, and converges the coefficients to match the OP's `real_voltage` coefficient for each antenna element.

```
# recreating OP's code but using matrix form to compute `total`
amplitude_norm_V=[0.3213,0.4336,0.7539,1,0.7817,0.3201,0.32,0.3261];
x=sqrt(1/(sum(amplitude_norm_V.^2)));
real_voltage=amplitude_norm_V.*x;
phases=[129.9121,175.4215,-144.6394,-116.9071,-93.7603,-60.0165,55.2841,89.4477]
theta=linspace(0,pi,1000);
f=5.6;
N=10;
lambda=300/f;
d=0.8*lambda;

ph = exp(1j*(pi*phases'/180)*ones(1, length(theta)));
z = [1:8]';
H = ph.*exp(-1j*(z-1)*k*d *(cos(theta)))
# OP's total given real_voltage
total = real_voltage * H;


# New code to solve for real_voltage given total.

num_elements = 8;            # total number of coefficients
nsamps = length(total);      # number of samples in target
iterations = 200;            # number of generations to test
trials = 100;                # number of children per generation
cn = zeros(1,num_elements);  # buffer for coefficients
rate = 1;                    # convergence rate
alpha = .2;                  # noise scaling for rate
A = ones(trials,nsamps);     # buffer for test patterns
min_error = ones(1,iterations);# buffer for error
for count = 1:iterations
  # test coefficients (children)  
  test_coeff = cn - rate * randn(trials, num_elements);
  # compute patterns for each child
  A = test_coeff * H;
  
  # fitness used is the unweighted mean square error
  fitness = rms((A - total),2) ;  # rms of each row
  
  # select best child (result buffered to plot error vs iteration)
  [min_error(count), idx]= min(fitness);
  cn = test_coeff(idx,:);
  
  #update rate for next generation
  rate = alpha * min_error(count);
endfor
```

The above is the MATLAB code with the phases fixed and derives the coefficients, but hopefully provides the right direction for the OP to expand this to converge on both the `phases` parameters in addition to the coefficients. The basic idea is to establish a metric of what is "good" (I used rms error between the target pattern and achieved pattern with equal weighting), compare several children in each generation where the parameters are changed by a random amount, and in a survival of the fittest strategy from nature, select the best child based on the metric used and from that create more children for the next generation. To accelerate convergence, a learning rate (step size in how much the next generation can change) was used that starts off larger when the errors are large and decreases as the solution converges.